# C++ Builder is StrToFloat() the same as .ToDouble()

Tags: c++, double, floating-point-precision, c++builder-xe6

I'm working in a XE6 project, but this may apply to other version of builder as well.

I'm looking at a function name, which I think may be misleading. I'm curious if `StrToFloat()` returns a `float` or if it returns a `double`. I found an alternative, which is `.ToDouble()` but we have a bunch of references in our code already that uses `StrToFloat()`. I wish to verify that I'm getting the proper precision that doubles offer.

I've done a couple tests like:

```
UnicodeString temp = "1234567890.12345678901234567890";
double a = StrToFloat(temp);
double b = temp.ToDouble();
```

These seem to give the same values from the tests I've done, but I wish to verify the `StrToFloat()` is the same as `.ToDouble()`

Answer (score 2):

I found enough references to answer my own question...

`StrToFloat()` returns an `extended` and an extended is a `long double`.

`.ToDouble()` returns a `double`.

So short answer is they are not the same, and vary as shown above.

References:

- `StrToFloat()`:
  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.SysUtils.StrToFloat
- `Extended`:
  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.Extended
- `.ToDouble()`:
  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.UnicodeString.ToDouble
- `long double` are more precise then `double` precision. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double

Comment: `.ToDouble()` calls `StrToFloat()` internally and returns the `Extended` as a `double` upon exit. Do pay attention to the `Extended` documentation, though. `Extended` is a `long double` on 32bit platforms, but is a `double` on Win64. The difference is that `double` is 8 bytes (64 bits) whereas `long double` is 10 bytes (80 bits). That is a 16bit [loss of precision on Win64](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Delphi_Considerations_for_Multi-Device_Applications#The_Extended_Data_Type_Is_2_Bytes_Smaller_on_64-bit_Windows_Systems).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That is very strange

Comment: @MooingDuck: It is due to a hardware limitation of 64bit CPUs. x86 natively supports 10-byte floating-point operations (hense why `Extended` existed in the first place), whereas x64 does not. Embarcadero does provide a `TExtended80Rec` type to handle 10-byte floating-point operations in x64, but of course the performance will not be the same as the CPU doing them natively.